# Github actions: Dependencies lock file is not found in runners/path

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a single Github repository for both server and frontend. The directory structure looks like:

```
root
  |- frontend
  |- server (Express App)
```

Github Action:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted
        
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci
      working-directory: './server'
    - run: npm run start
      working-directory: './server'
```

I only have a single job to build the Express server (and not the frontend yet) so I set the `working-directory` to `./server`. However, I still get an error:

```
Dependencies lock file is not found in /home/{username}/runners.../repository_name. Supported file patterns: package-lock.json,yarn.lock
```

So apparently it's not trying to run in `.../reposirtoy_name/server`.

[image]

I'm just trying to build both server and frontend in single Github action.

Comment: It seems it broke because the setup step (`Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}`) looked for those files at the repository root. Did you try executing a `run: cd server` between the first 2 steps?

Comment: Just a note, if your project does not have package-lock.json file, then using `npm ci` will fail.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There might be a chance that your problem is specifically with "uses: actions/setup-node". They mention in the docs that if you have **multiple lock files** or a lock file(s) in a **directory that is not the root**

In my case I had a single project with nested projects/dir. In my GitHub actions I wanted to run npm test on the nested project/dir so I had to specify to use my package.json inside the specific sub-directory. Double check to see that you are specifying the right directories with **cache-dependency-path**.

[image: docs]

Specified here
https://github.com/actions/setup-node#caching-global-packages-data

Answer (score 26):

Try out this solution. It worked in my case.
In the build insert the default working directory

```
build:
    runs-on: self-hosted    
    defaults:
       run:
         working-directory: ./server/
    strategy:
       matrix:
       node-version: [14.x]
```

Then include cache dependency path. This should be the location of your package-lock.json file

```
with:
    node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    cache: 'npm'
    cache-dependency-path: './server/package-lock.json'
```

Comment: Thank you. After hours of looking your answer was the only one that had no syntax errors with working directory and the cache and cache-dependency-paths.

Answer (score 6):

tldr

Make sure your checkout repo step is BEFORE setup node step, if using cache property with actions/setup-node@v3.

For me, it was caused by cache property on actions/setup-node@v3.
Without it - everything worked fine.
With it - failed. Reason is, it uses as cache key the package-lock.json (or yarn.lock) file.

See: https://github.com/actions/setup-node

My checkout repo step (actions/checkout@v2) was AFTER the setup node step, so it didn't find the package-lock.json file - because it wasn't checked out yet.

Comment: I have checkout setup, but it is still failed, can you check for me? https://github.com/dotku/meta-media/blob/main/.github/workflows/node.js.yml

Comment: @WeijingJayLin from what I see, ur yaml file is malformed. Missing indentation for everything under steps

Comment: I just added indentation, but it still won't have any new update.

Comment: @WeijingJayLin try without the matrix stuff

Answer (score 0):

May be is no append `actions/checkout@v3` before cache work.
I make a throuble about this reason.
The way can clone repo on runner.

```yaml
      - name: Check Out Response Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: echo "The ${{github.repository}} has been cloned to the runner"
      - run: echo "The workflow is now ready to test your code on the runner"
```